# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052. Laravel eloquent issue when joining table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have News table and the column in the blade table `posted by` is empty but in my news table the column `users_id` which is the posted by has a `users_id` value. I cant get the user who posted the specific news in specific school. I already have a working query for the news, but the problem is i cant join the `users` table where the `name` of the user who posted the news is in there. Can someone know what are the problem of my query? Help will be appreciated. Thanks

Index controller

```
public function index()
    {
        //testing query that returns an error
        $userschool = Newsboard::select('users.name', 'news.school_id')
                        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'news.users_id')
                        ->where('school_id', Auth::user()->school_id)->get();


         //the query that i want still returns an error because of the auth
        $postedby = DB::select(
            "SELECT news.*, users.name as postedby from news
            JOIN users on news.users_id = users.id
            WHERE news.school_id AND news.active = 1 AND news.school_id = 'Auth::user()->school_id'");


       //working queries and i dont know how to convert the $postedby query join to eloquent.
        if (Auth::user()->role == 0) {
            $news = Newsboard::where('active','=',1)->get();

        } elseif (Auth::user()->role == 1 || Auth::user()->role == 5) {

            $news = Newsboard::where('school_id', '=', Auth::user()->school_id ) 
                ->where('active','=',1)
                ->get();

        } else {
            $role = Auth::user()->role;
            $news = Newsboard::where('school_id', '=', Auth::user()->school_id  )
                ->where('status', '=', 1)
                ->where('active','=',1)
                ->whereRaw("group_id in('$role', '0')")
                ->get();

        }
        dd($userschool);

        return view('admin.pages.news.index', [
            'page_title' => $this->page_title,
            'news' => $news,
            'mnuname' => 'News',

        ]);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your Auth::user()->school_id as variable

```
$school_id = Auth::user()->school_id;

//the query that i want still returns an error because of the auth
$postedby = DB::select(
            "SELECT news.*, users.name as postedby from news
             JOIN users on news.users_id = users.id
             WHERE news.school_id AND news.active = 1 AND news.school_id = '$school_id'");
```

Or this:

```
Newsboard::select('users.name', 'news.school_id')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'news.users_id')
    ->where(['news.school_id' => $school_id])->get();
```

Comment: how do i convert it to eloquent sir and i want to insert the join query in it?

Comment: do i need to replace the `$news = Newsboard::where('users.name','news.school_id', '=', Auth::user()->school_id  )` Where into select sir?

Comment: @Vince Yes so you can reuse school_id without repeating the Auth also mark this answer as accepted if this help you

Comment: im scared if im going to change the `where` in the code. our senior makes the code and i solved it using this `->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'news.users_id')
                ->select('users.name AS postedby' , 'news.*')` i make an alias because the news name in table is `news` same in the `users` table

Comment: @Vince You can you use the where without array if your not passing multiple condition. also its good practice to reduce the redundant code in your function. Read some SOLID principles.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200040/discussion-between-poldo-and-vince).

Answer (score 1):

Because both `users` and `news` table contain `school_id` column, so in where condition must has `table` prefix.

Please try:

```php
$userschool = Newsboard::select('users.name', 'news.school_id')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'news.users_id')
    ->where('news.school_id', Auth::user()->school_id)->get();

//or 

//the query that i want still returns an error because of the auth
$postedby = DB::select("SELECT news.*, users.name as postedby from news
    JOIN users on news.users_id = users.id
    WHERE news.school_id AND news.active = 1 AND news.school_id = '".Auth::user()->school_id."'");
```

Comment: how do I insert that in my working queries sir? I wrote the two queries only for testing. Do you have any idea how to insert it? in my if statemetns?

Comment: because in my working queries i didint use `select` what should i do>

Answer (score 0):

```
$school_id = Auth::user()->school_id; 

$userschool = Newsboard::select('users.name', 'news.school_id')
                        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'news.users_id')
                        ->where('school_id', $school_id)->get();
```